# Slim - Change settings dynamically

Tags: php, slim

I would like to update the application's setting values dynamically after the route is determined. For example, in most of the routes, I have the timeout set to 600 seconds. This has been hard-coded in the setting file.

```
return [
'settings' => [
  'timeout' => 600,
....]
];
```

But in some special routes, I need to change the timeout to another value based on the input. e.g.

```
$app->get('/route1', function ($request, $response, $args) {
   $timeout = (some calculations from $args)
   $container['settings']['timeout'] = $timeout;
});
```

But I got this error when setting the timeout value to the container:

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of Slim\Collection has no effect
```

So what's the correct way to update the settings dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `$container['settings']` looks like an array access, it's actually a call to a closure that then returns an array which is why you get that notice. The solution is to retrieve the array and then modify it:

```
$settings = $container['settings'];
$settings['timeout'] = $timeout;
```